# c# - Find element value in an Object within a List within Dictionnary

Tags: c#, list, object, dictionary, find

I'm currently in needs of creating a Dictionary like that :

```
public Dictionary<MyFirstObject, List<MySecondObject>> _reference { get; set; }
```

These 2 objects store datas which need to be match during the process. This is why I used a Dictionary. The Objects looks like that :

```
public class MyFirstObject
{
    public string _element1 ;
    public MyThirdObject _element2;

    public MyFirstObject(string element1, MyThirdObject element2)
    {
        _element1 = element1;
        _element2 = element2;
    }
}
public class MySecondObject
{
    public string _element3;
    public string _element4;
    public string _element5;

    public MySecondObject(string element3, string element4, string element5)
    {
        _element3 = element3;
        _element4 = element4;
        _element5 = element5;
    }
}
```

---

Than I would like to get the "**MyFirstObject**" which contain some data inside, for example I succeed to find the "**_element1**" and I got the related "**MyFirstObject**" of this request :

```
MyFirstObject mfo = _reference.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Key._element1 == "mySearch").Key
```

This code works ! I think that I could easily find the _element2 without problem.
Now, I would like to do the same thing with the "**Dictionary.Value**" and find, for example, the "**_element3**".

I tried this code :

```
MyFirstObject mfo = _reference.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.FirstOrDefault(z => z._element3 == "mySearch")).Key;
```

I used the "**.Key**" at the end because I would like to get the relative "**MyFirstObject**" of this request. But this request doesn't work.

Can you help me to success this request please ?

Thanks

EDIT : the error message is : "**Cannot implicitly convert type 'MySecondObject' to 'bool'**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = _reference.FirstOrDefault(x => 
                      x.Value.Any(z => z._element3 == "mySearch"));
if (result.Key != null)
    MyFirstObject mfo = result.Key;
```

Comment: Why are you verifying the result value ?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` returns `null` if nothing matches the predicate

Comment: Thank you for your answer. however, the for the "if (result != null)", Visual Studio said that "it cannot convert type 'System.Collection.Generic.KeyValuePair<MyFristObject,System.Collections.Generic.List<MySecondObject>> to 'bool'. Do you have an idea for that error ?

Comment: Yes my bad. `result` is a struct, it will never be null. You can test for existance and change the test to `if (test.Key != null)`